# What is the best way to upload a (requested) file with jersey?

Tags: java, upload, jersey

## Information

Currently I have two different methods to upload a (requested) file with Jersey:

- Method 1 returns a StreaminOutput
- Method 2 returns a Response

---

```
@GET
@Path("download-file1/{fileName}")
public StreamingOutput downloadFile1(@PathParam("fileName") final String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    final File file = new File("path/to/my/dir/" + fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException;
    }

    return new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            Files.copy(file, output);
        }
    };
}

@GET
@Path("download-file2/{fileName}")
public Response downloadFile2(@PathParam("fileName") final String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    final File file = new File("path/to/my/dir/" + fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException;
    }

    ResponseBuilder rb = null;
    rb = Response.ok((java.lang.Object)file);
    rb.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    return rb.build();
}
```

---

## Question

Which of these two functions can I use best to upload (all types of) files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option from far away is streamoption as far as you won't load the whole file on server memory and as far as it would stream the file thrue the web. 
Enjoy :)